# how to set MTU value in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, netsh, mtu

I wish to change the **MTU** value on my pc (**XP**)

i tried some **registry** mathods- added some values in several places:

1. (this one is a windows tutorial)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ndiswan\Parameters\Protocols\0

adding:

ProtocolType

PPPProtocolType

ProtocolMTU

2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip\parameters\\

   adding an MTU value.
3. tried to add the "EnablePMTUDiscovery" at the following path:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip\parameters\

---

Also tried netsh (in cmd) :

netsh interface **ipv4** set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=576 store=persistent

But apperently-i don't have the "ipv4" option- didn't find how to add it.

is there a solution to one of the options above' or another one

Answer (score 1):

You can't set mtu in windows xp with netsh. Only the registry.

Here is a link to the KB Article for that  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;283165

You can also use a 3rd party program like Dr.TCP.  http://www.dslreports.com/drtcp